# I have the following XML and i need to store it in a sql table

Tags: sql, xml, database, vb.net

i need the tags ServerName, DBName, UserName, RoleName. I can not access to these tags, because the first part of the xml is creating me troubles

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>Selected.System.Object</T>
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <S N="ServerName">DDW</S>
      <S N="DBName">dwSeriesOLAP</S>
      <S N="UserName">123Z</S>
      <S N="RoleName">test1</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="1">
   <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <S N="ServerName">DDW</S>
      <S N="DBName">dwSeriesOLAP</S>
      <S N="UserName">1234</S>
      <S N="RoleName">test2</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="2">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <S N="ServerName">DDW</S>
      <S N="DBName">dwSeriesOLAP</S>
      <S N="UserName">12345aa</S>
      <S N="RoleName">test3</S>
    </MS>
   </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Comment: So you have a problem with the default namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML there are two different structures:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>Selected.System.Object</T>
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <S N="ServerName">DDW</S>
      <S N="DBName">dwSeriesOLAP</S>
      <S N="UserName">123Z</S>
      <S N="RoleName">test1</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="1">
   <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <S N="ServerName">DDW</S>
      <S N="DBName">dwSeriesOLAP</S>
      <S N="UserName">1234</S>
      <S N="RoleName">test2</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="2">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <S N="ServerName">DDW</S>
      <S N="DBName">dwSeriesOLAP</S>
      <S N="UserName">12345aa</S>
      <S N="RoleName">test3</S>
    </MS>
   </Obj>
</Objs>';
```

--The query for your first element with `<TN>`

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04')
SELECT obj.value('@RefId','int') AS ObjectId
      ,obj.value('(TN/@RefId)[1]','int') AS TNId
      ,t.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS T_Content
FROM @xml.nodes('/Objs/Obj[TN]') A(obj) --<-- see the predicate for `[TN]`
CROSS APPLY A.obj.nodes('TN/T') B(t);
```

--Alternative for the previous if you can be sure, that there is just one single `<TN>` element:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04')
SELECT @xml.value('(/Objs/Obj[TN]/@RefId)[1]','int') AS ObjectId
      ,@xml.value('(/Objs/Obj[TN]/TN/@RefId)[1]','int') AS TNId
      ,t.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS T_Content
FROM @xml.nodes('/Objs/Obj[TN]/TN/T') A(t);
```

--the query for the repeating `<MS><S>` elements

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04')
SELECT obj.value('@RefId','int') AS ObjectId
      --if appropriate you might use COALLESCE for the TN-ids
      ,obj.value('(TN/@RefId)[1]','int') AS TNId
      ,obj.value('(TNRef/@RefId)[1]','int') AS TNRefId
      ,obj.value('(MS/S[@N="ServerName"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ServerName
      ,obj.value('(MS/S[@N="DBName"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DBName
      ,obj.value('(MS/S[@N="UserName"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS UserName
      ,obj.value('(MS/S[@N="RoleName"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS RoleName
FROM @xml.nodes('/Objs/Obj') A(obj)
```

--and one more to retrieve each embedded structure separately. This allows for a step-wise approach (e.g. with an intermediate staging table).

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04')
,TheObjects AS
(
    SELECT obj.value('@RefId','int') AS ObjectId
          ,obj.query('TN') AS TN_Element 
          ,obj.query('TNRef') AS TNRef_Element 
          ,obj.query('MS') AS MS_Element 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Objs/Obj') A(obj)
)
SELECT * 
FROM TheObjects;
```

The idea in short:

- We need to declare the existing default namespace
- we use `.nodes()` to dive into repeating elements
- We use `.value()` to retrieve data (either from `@xml` directly or from a Xml fragment coming from `.nodes()`).
- We use `.query()` to retrieve Xml fragments.

Comment: Perfect, this works fine. The first element was the one giving me headaches. I appreciate your help much!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a DDL and sample data population... You can edit your original pot and add them. Also, please share your T-SQL attempt too.

In any case, as @zx485 pointed out, you have a default namespace in the root element. So you need to define it and everything will work. Along the following:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for **SQL Server** and you have your data in a `@XmlData` variable - you can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @xmldata XML = '...... (your XML here) .......`;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04')
SELECT
    ServerName = XC.value('(S[@N="ServerName"])[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    DBName = XC.value('(S[@N="DBName"])[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    UserName = XC.value('(S[@N="UserName"])[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    RoleName = XC.value('(S[@N="RoleName"])[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @xmldata.nodes('/Objs/Obj/MS') AS XT(XC)
```

That should give you an output something like this:

[image]